# No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"cupboards", :user_id=>"19"} missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to redirect a user, after having created a new 'cupboard' to the user_cupboard_path.  I keep getting a `missing required keys[:id]` error

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"cupboards", :id=>nil, :user_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id, :user_id]
```

This is the params the error screen is giving me

```
   {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"MmxYdBmGHgMTcyw3fVz0/Lmw7TbFtOxDlKKEDtbPTZgfger08QSGxc4+1qkEXOLzurDne+55V6SUBqXAx+g==",
 "style"=>"ATHLEISURE",
 "commit"=>"Create Cupboard",
 "user_id"=>"19"}
```

cupboards controller

```
def create
  @cupboard = Cupboard.new(cupboard_params)
 if @cupboard.save
   redirect_to user_cupboard_path(@cupboard)
 else
   render :new
 end
end
```

routes

```
resources :users do
 resources :cupboards
end
```

The record is being created through because I can manually type in the URL

```
localhost3000/users/:id/cupboards/:id
```

I have tried to do the following in the `redirect_to` statement...

```
redirect_to user_cupboard_path(@cupboard)
redirect_to user_cupboard_path(@user)
redirect_to user_cupboard_path(@user, @cupboard)
redirect_to user_cupboard_path(cupboard)
redirect_to user_cupboard_path(user)
```

None have worked

I'm certain it's just a newbie mistake, something simple i'm overlooking. Any help is appreciated!

Sam

Comment: double  check that `@cupboard.persisted?` before you try and redirect - the `.save` call may have failed, and you'd need to check `@cupboard.errors.full_messages` to se why

Comment: Can you post your show action?

Comment: Have you defined `@user`?

Comment: Try `redirect_to user_cupboard_path(@cupboard.user_id, @cupboard.id)`.

Comment: post your strong parameters method for `cupboard_params`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `User` has_many `Cupboards`, you should modify your create action.

```
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @cupboard = @user.cupboards.new(cupboard_params)
 if @cupboard.save
   redirect_to user_cupboard_path(@cupboard)
 else
   render :new
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, problem fixed, mainly thanks to Pramod

Changed my controller to

```
  def create
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @cupboard = @user.cupboards.new(cupboard_params)
 if @cupboard.save
   redirect_to user_cupboard_path(@user, @cupboard)
 else
   render :new
 end
end
```

Additionally, Pramod made me second guess my model setup. Turns out I also forgot to have a `has_many :users` in my User model.